# Resilient MongoDB Applications in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working through [this](https://emptysqua.re/blog/how-to-write-resilient-mongodb-applications/) blog and associated video, attempting to implement a retry mechanism in my mongodb Data Access Objects.

The gist of the article is to build data access routines that make a sensible choice about whether or not it is worth retrying an operation in the case of failure. I'm pretty happy that I understand what the article is suggesting, but I'm finding it difficult to implement in Java.

The article contains pseudo-code like the following for an `insertOne` operation:

```
doc = {_id: ObjectId(), ...}
try:
  insertOne(doc)
except network err:
    try:
        insertOne(doc)
    except DuplicateKeyError:
        pass  # first try worked
    throw
```

My difficulty comes in working out which exceptions I am interested in catching in the `except network err` statement. The Mongo Exception model is fairly complex and the javadocs aren't clear about what circumstances result in which exceptions.

Has anyone implemented this in Java and can point me in the right direction regarding which exceptions I need top be concerned about?

Comment: I guess it depends on the driver/lib you use to communicate with mongoDB. Are you using the official java driver?

Comment: @p.streef : I'm using org.mongodb.mongo-java-driver : 3.4.2 which is, as far as I know, the official driver.

Comment: I've never implemented this myself (I usualy use spring-data) but I would say that network errors are the only ones worth retrying. If there is something else wrong it is probably going to be wrong the second time as well. So I would look at MongoSocketException and go from there.

Comment: Thanks - that's the conclusion I came to as well, but I feel a bit like I may be missing something. For the write operations I think I'll also have to check whatever exception ( I don't have to docs with me right now ) is thrown when the primary switches.

Comment: What kind of write exceptions would you expect to solve by retrying?

Comment: The driver knows about the nodes in the replica set, including the one it considers to be the primary. If, between the driver getting the last state of the nodes in the replica set and the current write operation, the primary had crashed or some other re-election had occurred, our write would go to a secondary and be rejected. When this happens, the driver returns the exception, but also re-interrogates the replica set status before returning the exception. When we retry, the driver now knows the correct primary and will dispatch the write to it. ( That's what the blog post says anyway )